# $W$ contains at least one non-singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

> Denote $M_n(\mathbb R)$ to be the vector space of all real matrices of order $n$. Assume $W$ is a linear subspace of $M_n(\mathbb R)$, and $\dim W \geqslant n^2-n+1$. Prove that $W$ contains *at least* one non-singular matrix.

I am clueless about this question. Can anyone help?